# Not able to see the final result after the Reduce function got executed using Windows Azure Storage in MapReduce

Tags: c#, hadoop, azure-storage, hadoop-streaming

I am using `c#.net` for writing the map and reduce function.I have basically followed the example being given [here](https://www.hadooponazure.com/Account/SampleDetail/84)

*Final command*

**Hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -files "hdfs:///example/apps/map.exe,hdfs:///example/apps/reduce.exe" -input "/example/apps/data.csv" -output "/example/apps/output.txt" -mapper "map.exe" -reducer "reduce.exe"**

The Job ran successfully[image]

Now from the Interactive JS mode, if I write

```
js> #cat /example/apps/output.txt
```

**cat: File does not exist: /example/apps/output.txt**

Where as :

```
js> #ls /example/apps/output.txt
```

Found 3 items

```
-rw-r--r-- 3 xxxx supergroup 0 2013-02-22 10:23 /example/apps/output.txt/_SUCCESS

drwxr-xr-x - xxxx supergroup 0 2013-02-22 10:22 /example/apps/output.txt/_logs

-rw-r--r-- 3 xxxx supergroup 0 2013-02-22 10:23 /example/apps/output.txt/part-00000
```

What is the mistake I am making and how can I see the output?

Comment: as per the log ,i think you should be able to see at /example/apps/output.txt

Comment: No...still not able to see the output.I have updated the new findings.

Comment: part-00000 under output.txt is your output file,just cat it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-output` flag specifies an output folder, not a file. Since there can be multiple reducers, each one will produce a file in this folder.

In this case, you have one reducer, and it produced one file: `part-00000`. If there were more reducers, they would be named `part-00001`, `part-00002`, etc.

The command `cat /example/apps/output.txt/part-00000` will display your output. In the future, don't name your output folders `something.txt`, as that will just confuse you and others :)